# MongoDB find among subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

I have a bunch of documents where each of them is formatted this way:

```
{
  "faculty": "Some Faculty",
  "students": [
      {
        "id": "51230867123",
        "age": "21",
        "name": "awdawdawdawawd"
      },
      {
        "id": "0217356102",
        "age": "22",
        "name": "awdawd"
      },
      ...
      ]
}
```

I've inserted those documents into a single MongoDB collection using `insertMany([...])`, so now my `students` table looks like this:

```
{
  "faculty": "Some Faculty",
  "students": [
      {
        "id": "51230867123",
        "age": "21",
        "name": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "id": "0217356102",
        "age": "22",
        "name": "Jane Doe"
      },
      ...
      ]
},
{
  "faculty": "Other Faculty",
  "students": [
      {
        "id": "1240876124",
        "age": "21",
        "name": "Jimmy Doe"
      },
      {
        "id": "2309857120578",
        "age": "22",
        "name": "Johnny Doe"
      },
      ...
      ]
},
...
```

I'd very much like to find out how I can perform a `find` query on certain subdocuments, specifically `students`. For example, I'd like to `find` all `students.name` with `students.age > 23`. I've tried many queries, including `db.students.find({"students.age": {$gt: /.*B.*/}}, {_id: 0, "students.name": 1})`, but such queries always return whole documents for which at least one student fulfills the condition. I'd like to query individual students. Is this possible using `find` (no `aggregate`)?

With `aggregate`, one can use `unwrap`, which is pretty much exactly what I need to do. I'm however hoping for some tricks to use with `find` to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation operator in projection of find and findOne method, starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of students array and check required condition, it will return filtered result
- `$map` to iterate loop of above filtered result and return only `name`

```
db.collection.find(
  { "students.age": { $gt: "23" } },
  {
    "students": {
      $map: {
        input: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$students",
            cond: { $gt: ["$$this.age", "23"] }
          }
        },
        in: "$$this.name"
      }
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XkbxIroDtZq)

Comment: Bit curious though that you specified the condition twice. Is that required for this approach?

Comment: yes it requires, the query part filters main root document and projection filters matches object from array of students.